# VB sleep() calls all executing immediately, instead of sequentially in the order of my code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, sleep

I am designing a blackjack game for a school project, and when the first hand  is dealt, i would like the first card to appear for the player, then the dealers first card, then player card, dealer card. 
I am using system.threading.thread.sleep(1000) to pause in between the cards being dealt, so they dont all appear at once. for some reason, the sleeps all execute at once, before any cards appear. so it will pause for 3 seconds, then deal all cards instead of executing at the line where i coded it:

```
Private Sub dealHand()
    Dim playerScore As Integer = 0,
        playerScoreA As Integer = 0,
        dealerScore As Integer = 0,
        dealerScoreA As Integer = 0

    Dim card1 As Integer = newCard(True),
        card2 As Integer = newCard(False),
        card3 As Integer = newCard(False),
        card4 As Integer = newCard(False)



    playerCardPic1.Image = cardImgList.Images(card1)
    playerScore = cardValue(card1)
    playerScoreA = checkAce(card1, playerScore, True)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

    dealerCardPic1.Image = My.Resources.ImpsBackDesign
    dealerScore = cardValue(card2)
    dealerScoreA = checkAce(card2, dealerScore, False)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

    playerCardPic2.Image = cardImgList.Images(card3)
    playerCardPic2.Visible = True
    playerScore += cardValue(card3)
    playerScoreA += checkAce(card3, playerScore, True)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

    dealerCardPic2.Image = cardImgList.Images(card4)
    dealerCardPic2.Visible = True
    dealerScore += cardValue(card4)
    dealerScoreA += checkAce(card4, dealerScore, False)

    pScoreLbl.Text = playerScore.ToString
    pAceLbl.Text = "or " & playerScoreA.ToString
    dScoreLbl.Text = dealerScore.ToString
    dAceLbl.Text = "or " & dealerScoreA.ToString

    If playerScore <> playerScoreA Then
        aceLabel(playerScoreA, True)
    End If

    If dealerScore <> dealerScoreA Then
        aceLabel(dealerScoreA, False)
    End If

    checkPScore(playerScore, playerScoreA)

    hitBtn.Enabled = True
    standBtn.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `Thread.Sleep suspends the current thread for the specified amount of time.` Why do you think that, while sleeping, your thread could draw the cards?

Comment: it's simply because the GUI didn't have a chance yet to update, before it exits your sub. Since your sub is blocking the GUI thread, it only updates what you asked for once it reaches End Sub (so yes, it is true, it waits for 3 seconds and then processes all queued GUI events (like dealing the cards))

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by refreshing the GUI with me.refresh() before the sleep pauses. Much thanks!